# Verify that $\sqrt{2}\left\| z \right\| \ge \left|\Re(z)\right| + \left|\Im(z)\right|$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Verify that  $\sqrt{2}\left\| z \right\| \ge \left|\Re(z)\right| + \left|\Im(z)\right|.$

I started off noting that $z=x+iy$ and that $Re(z)=x$ and $Im(z)=y$

Then I know that I have to square both sides, giving me

$$2(x^2 +y^2) \ge x^2+2|xy|+y^2$$

I'm not sure what to do after this.

Comment: $$\iff(x-y)^2\ge0$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, using that property, would I then be able to say  that $(x-y)^2$ is equal to $x^2 + y^2 -2xy$. and then maybe adding $x^2 + y^2$ to both sides??

Comment: @cele Your Mathjax code does not work. I was about to fix it but I don't understand the point of these \lefts and \rights. Could you rewrite the code yourself, for example following this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Comment: @JiK  its suppose to be absolute value, but let me work on fixing it

Comment: @cele You can get the absolute value by `\left| x \right|`, or simply by `|x|` if there's no need to get | signs of different size.

Comment: \left and \right are 'markers' indicating that the character that follows them is a delimiter; they're not symbols in their own right.

Comment: Thank you, I was working on fixing it but i guess i was a little too slow.

Comment: You could try writing $z=x+iy$ with $x$ and $y$ real, and express the inequality in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $z=x+iy$. We have $(x-y)^2\geq 0$, therefore 
\begin{align}
2|z|^2=2\big(|x|^2+|y|^2\big)&\geq |x|^2+|y|^2+2|x||y|\\
&=\big(|x|+|y|\big)^2\\
&=\big(|\Re(z)|+|\Im(z)|\big)^2
\end{align}
so we have that
$$\sqrt2\,|z|\:\geq|\:\Re (z)|+|\Im (z)|\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $z = a + ib$ Then we have:

$$\sqrt{2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \geq |a| + |b| $$
$$\sqrt{2(a^2+b^2)} \geq |a| + |b| $$
$$ 2(a^2+b^2) \geq (|a| + |b|)^2$$

Try to simplify it so LHS is an expression, and the right hand side is $0$. Notice what the left hand side is and confirm the equality.